# linq2db: can't generate POCOs for tables

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, t4, linq2db

As I need to work with C# and MySQL, I recently installed linq2db via its NuGet package. Once installed, I found out it came with a very sweet feature which is unmentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db): a set of T4 templates to auto-generate DB class and tables' POCOs! (WOW!)

So I decided to run T4s instead of write down my POCOs by myself, but here comes the wrong part: **tables list for the db is not found**, thus only the db class is created.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but perhaps also interesting for others looking for information on linq2db templates: [ReadMe.LinqToDB.md](https://github.com/linq2db/t4models/blob/master/Templates/ReadMe.LinqToDB.md)

Answer (score 1):

The following demo project generates tables for MySql
https://github.com/linq2db/examples/tree/master/MySql/GetStarted/DataModels

Comment: ...which does exactly what I do. Going inside through the debugger, i found out the problem is that when LoadMySqlMetadata() runs, it gets schema infos but not table list. Maybe is something with the db user priviledges? I'm root anyway

Comment: I don't know mysql but in SQL Server being machine administrator doesn't automatically give you the system administrator role in SQL Server. What happens if you run the query LoadMySqlMetadata does manually?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the auto generated classes.

Are you *sure* that you completed step 2?
It refers to modifying the line after the end of the comments (after the description of step 5) from

```
LoadMySqlMetadata("MyServer", "MyDatabase", "root", "TestPassword");
```

to something sensible.
After that, you'll get a 'sub'-file of the `CopyMeMysql.tt` (in VS, click expand icon to the left of the file in the project) called `CopyMeMysql.generated.cs`.